# PHP is giving unexpected results from epoch time conversion

Tags: php, time, epoch

I need to convert an epoch time to standard Hour and Minutes. Using various examples found on Stackoverflow, I have been unable to get the correct return. I am using the following

```
$seconds= 1495587600;   
$mytime= date("H:i", $seconds);
echo $mytime."<br>";
```

I have checked the value of $seconds on a time converter site and get the correct result. I would expect the return from the code to be 09:00, instead I get 01:00. Is there something I am leaving out?

Comment: Working fine on my side , I got 21:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a time zone issue. PHP date() works using the local time zone which can be set with `date_default_timezone_set()`. Your hosting company or some other server configuration may be setting a different default time zone than what you expect.

Comment: Something is wrong, I echo the time zone and it's correct as is the standard time and epoch time. But as I run the code for the value of seconds it's incorrect. Maybe my code is wrong. Trying to convert epoch to h:i in standard time.

Comment: @snowman 1:00 is what you should get if you are set for UTC.  How are you echoing the time zone? date_default_timezone_get() or something else?

Comment: echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>";

Comment: AMERICA/NEW_YORK

Comment: @snowman With 'America/New_York' you should get 21:00 as the result. Of the other times listed above, 1:00 is what you should get for UTC and 09:00 would be someplace on the other side of the world. But 21:00 = 9:00 PM, so if you are trying to get 9:00 PM then use 'h' instead of 'H' for 12-hour time and you can add AM/PM with 'a' or 'A'.

Comment: I found it! For some reason I overlooked a line in code where I had set time zone to UTC later in script. Duhhhhh. Thanks for taking the time to guide me in right direction.

Comment: @snowman No problem. Time zones can get very tricky, especially around DST transitions.